# Configuring and Developing iOS part of Flutter Part

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, flutter

I want to create a Feature Detector Plugin for iOS and Android using a Flutter Plugin.

I got the Android (and Java) part running and can access it via MessageChannels.
Adding the iOS isn't working, because there is no xcode-workspace file. Also the integration for the OpenCV.framework via Wrapper.h, -.mm and binding-file.h won't work.

I used the official OpenCV Bindings for iOS from this [site](https://www.opencv.org/releases.html).

For some reasons the auto-completion isn't working and my bindings don't get recognized in the Swift file.

When trying to debug the code via flutter in VS code it mentioned that the WrapperClass couldn't be found.

I tried adding an Xcode project myself, but using the empty option isn't enough or the right option.

The code can be found in my repo: https://github.com/MTschannett/image_feature_detector

I'm no very new to Swift, Objective-C, and C++. Is there some guideline for how to use iOS packages in Swift?

How can I integrate OpenCV to the iOS part of my plugin?